# How to combine querysets retaining annotate fields?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, orm

I have two different queries for the same table:

```py
 m_i = MyModel.objects.filter(
            user__profile__newsletter=True
        ).annotate(name=F('user__profile__complete_name'))\
        .values('name')\
        .annotate(indicado=Count('user'))\
        .order_by('user__profile__complete_name')
```

and

```py
m_e = MyModel.objects.filter(
            user__profile__newsletter=True,
            chosen=True)\
        ).annotate(name=F('user__profile__complete_name'))\
        .values('name')\
        .annotate(escolhido=Count('user'))\
        .order_by('user__profile__complete_name')
```

The queries are very much the same except for one filter in the second and I annotate this same value for the both of them but they come out with different values. Right now the querysets are like this:

```py
# m_i
[{name:'ex1', indicado: 1},
{name:'ex2', indicado: 2},
{name:'ex3', indicado: 9},
{name:'ex4', indicado: 3}]

# m_e
[{name:'ex1', escolhido: 1},
{name:'ex2', escolhido: 1},
{name:'ex3', escolhido: 4},
{name:'ex4', escolhido: 2}]
```

I wanted to unite the querysets so I could have something like this:

```py
# union
[{name:'ex1', escolhido: 1, indicado: 1},
{name:'ex2', escolhido: 1, , indicado: 2},
{name:'ex3', escolhido: 4, , indicado: 9},
{name:'ex4', escolhido: 2, , indicado: 3}]
```

I tried using the method `union` like this `m_i.union(m_e)` but it seems as if it assumes that `indicado` and `escolhido` are the same thing and retains only one of the two. Using `itertools.chain` returns to me the both querysets one after the other, not united by the same key. Is there a way to union them both without iterating on the querysets? I can go over all of the items because it can have hundreds of rows.

btw: My database is mysql 1.4 and django is 2.1 and no, sadly I can't update none of them both :(

Answer (score 0):

Found the soluction for myself. For anybody that stumble uppon the same problem that I did here's what I done now:

```py
md = MyModel.objects.
        ...
        .annotate(escolhido=Count('user', filter=Q(chosen=True)))\
        .annotate(indicado=Count('user'))\
```

Instead of filtering the whole queryset you can just filter in the `aggregation function`.